# Drawing transparent ShapeRenderer in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a drawn a filled circle using ShapeRenderer and now I want to draw this circle as a transparent one. I am using the following code to do that: But the circle is not coming as transparent. Also, I checked th libgdx API and from the wiki, it says that, need to Create CameraStrategy. Has somebody faced similar issue ever before? If so, please  give me some clues. Thanks in advance.

```
 Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
      Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
      drawFilledCircle();
      Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);

private void drawFilledCircle(){

   shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
   shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.FilledCircle);
   shapeRenderer.setColor(new Color(0, 1, 0, 1));
   shapeRenderer.filledCircle(470, 45, 10);
   shapeRenderer.end();

}
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why do you want to draw a transparent circle?

Comment: @crynix, basically I need to understand how can I use ShapeRenderer to display transparancy. I do not want to use a transparent texture here for that. So I wanted to do using ShapeRenederer.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The following code is working for me in this case, maybe it will help someone else:

```
Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.FilledCircle);
shapeRenderer.setColor(new Color(0, 1, 0, 0.5f));
shapeRenderer.filledCircle(470, 45, 10);
shapeRenderer.end();
Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
```

Comment: Thanks it working but i hope i doesnt mess with other blend stuffs if any

Comment: Enabling and disabling blend worked for me also.. however I share @Max_Dev's concern that this might not be the most efficient thing here.

Comment: It is VERY IMPORTANT to stop/pause the current SpriteBatch using
mySpriteBatch.end() BEFORE enabling blending! Translucent drawing operations won't work otherwise! :D

Comment: This doesn't need to be before `shapeRenderer.begin()` but it does need to be before `shapeRenderer.setColor()`.

Comment: Note: you shouldn't allocate new Color instance on each frame.

Comment: @Miha_x64 you are right. But that was a  code snippet only, not the actual code

Comment: Had to change `GL10` to `GL20` to get it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

First we need to enable blending:

```
Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
```

And make sure that you don't call `SpriteBatch.begin()` and `SpriteBatch.end()` between that line of code and your `Shaperender.drawSomething()` line of code. I don't know why but that's what works in my case

Comment: Replace `GL10` with `GL20` for newer versions of LibGDX.

Comment: Replace `GL20` with `GL30` for newer versions of LibGDX.

Comment: `GL30` extends `GL20` and `GL30.GL_BLEND` is a static reference to `GL20.GL_BLEND`.

Answer (score 6):

**Only** this worked for me :

```
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
//Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);   // <<< this line here makes the magic we're after
game.shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
game.shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    go.drawShapes();
game.shapeRenderer.end();
//Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
```

Comment: Same thing happened with me. LibGDX discontinued support of OpenGL version 1.x sometime last year. This is likely just the result of using a newer version.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there is not really a point in drawing something fully transparent. If you did want to make a half transparent circle, you would have to clear the color buffer by `glClearColor` before each frame and set `Color` alpha component to `0.5f`.

*If you wouldn't clear the buffer, after few render draws, the circle would blend into one with almost solid color.*

```
private void drawFilledCircle(Camera camera){
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    Gdx.gl.glClear( GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT  );

    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.FilledCircle);
    shapeRenderer.setColor(new Color(0, 1, 0, 0.5f)); // last argument is alpha channel
    shapeRenderer.filledCircle(470, 45, 10);
    shapeRenderer.end();
}
```

Comment: ,In my case with the above change, I cannot see the transparancy

Comment: For some reason alpha in color works in debug mode (drawing borders of scene2ui elements). But without debug mode I got solid non-transparent colors (same result when alpha is 1f). I'm clearing buffer before every frame.